# Oracle returns no rows when executing from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle

I have a strange problem. This is the Code snippet

**CODE**

```
Dim dt = model.FrmDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBSTRING").ConnectionString
objConnection = New OleDbConnection(strConnection)
objConnection.Open()
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM CHESTER WHERE SUBMIT_DATE=TO_DATE('" & dt & "','DD-MON-YYYY')"
objCmd = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, objConnection)
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader()
```

After executing the above code, the reader returns nothing. I also changed the strSQL as 
    `strSQL = "SELECT * FROM CHESTER WHERE SUBMIT_DATE=TO_DATE('17-Jul-2014','DD-MON-YYYY')"` but with no success. The same code (using both strSQL) runs perfectly in sql navigator and it return rows as expected but it fails to return row when executing via asp.net mvc. (Addn: oracle NLS_DATE_FORMAT is DD-Mon-RRRR). Please help me to sort out the issue.

**EDIT**

If I give SYSDATE instead of '17-Jul-2014' it return rows in the above query. So I think the problem is in between single quotation. But the same return rows in sql navigator / sql plus

Comment: One possibility is that you are connected to the wrong database or to the wrong server.  Is an error returned from the statement?

Comment: No gordon.. If I exclude the date in my query then i can get the rows. I think the problem might be in NLS_DATE_FORMAT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of search and using trial and error method, Finally got the result. If I use trunc(SUBMIT_DATE) then i got the expected rows. The updated query as follows:

CODE

`strSQL = "SELECT * FROM CHEST_DENOM WHERE TRUNC(SUBMIT_DATE)='" & dt & "'"`

It may help others who have same problem